# Error 403 when making GET-request in axios

Tags: axios, python-requests, get, http-status-code-403

I have this code in python:

```
def getStockXImage(query):
    url = "https://stockx.com"
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) ' +
                      'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) ' +
                      'Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36'
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

and this code in axios:

```
var axios = require("axios").default;

var my_url = "https://stockx.com/";
var my_user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36"

var query = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: my_url,
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': my_user_agent,
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept': '*/*',
  }
};

axios.request(query).then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.error(error.message);
});
```

The python code is working but I get 403 (Forbidden) when running the axios code. I've checked through pipedream so that they have identical headers and everything seems identical.